# How can remove http(s), www(n) and public suffixes in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

Input => Expected Output

1. `https://mail.google.com.au` => `mail.google`
2. `http://www.google.in` => `google`
3. `https://www9.calendar.google.co.uk` => `calendar.google`
4. `https://www12.stage.calendar.google.co.uk` => `stage.calendar.google`
5. `www.blog.botreetechnologies.com` => `blog.botreetechnologies`

**Update**

```
t = URI.parse 'http://www.google.com'
t.host
#=> "www.google.com"

URI.split 'http://www.google.com'
#=> ["http", nil, "www.google.com", nil, nil, "", nil, nil, nil]
uri = URI.parse("http://www.google.co.uk")
#=> #<URI::HTTP http://www.google.co.uk>
domain = PublicSuffix.parse(uri.host)
#=> #<PublicSuffix::Domain:0x00000003c538e0 @sld="google", @tld="co.uk", @trd="www">
domain.sld
#=> "google"

uri = URI.parse("http://www.mail.google.co.uk")
#=> #<URI::HTTP http://www.mail.google.co.uk>
domain = PublicSuffix.parse(uri.host)
#=> #<PublicSuffix::Domain:0x00000002e97bc0 @sld="google", @tld="co.uk", @trd="www.mail">
domain.sld
#=> "google"

%w[http://www.example.com/page http://blog.example.com/page].each do |u|
  puts URI.parse(u).host.sub(/^www\./, '')  
end  
# example.com
# blog.example.com

uri = URI.parse("www.pinkpoodles.com.au")
#=> #<URI::Generic www.pinkpoodles.com.au>
uri.host
#=> nil
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: [publicsuffix-ruby](https://github.com/weppos/publicsuffix-ruby) should help to strip the public suffixes.

Comment: @Зелёный I update the post with what I tried. I was looking for quick single line solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how I fixed that then. On a toe so pasting quickly

```
def filename(website_domain)
  domain = website_domain.starts_with?('http') ? website_domain : "https://#{website_domain}"
  uri = URI.parse domain
  suffix = PublicSuffix.parse(uri.host)
  name = uri.host.sub(/^www\d*\./i, '').sub(/\.#{suffix.tld}/, '')
  "#{name}.filtered.xml"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a "one-liner", but something like this would work:

```
require 'uri'
require 'public_suffix'

def simple_host(uri)
  uri = URI(uri)
  uri = URI("http://#{uri}") unless uri.scheme
  domain = PublicSuffix.parse(uri.host)
  trd = domain.trd
  if trd
    trd = trd.split('.')
    trd.shift if trd.first.start_with?('www')
  end
  [*trd, domain.sld].join('.')
end

simple_host('https://mail.google.com.au')                #=> "mail.google"
simple_host('http://www.google.in')                      #=> "google"
simple_host('https://www9.calendar.google.co.uk')        #=> "calendar.google"
simple_host('https://www12.stage.calendar.google.co.uk') #=> "stage.calendar.google"
simple_host('www.blog.botreetechnologies.com')           #=> "blog.botreetechnologies"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a job for one line. But here's a function that does some string manipulation that at least satisfies the test cases you have provided.

```
def foo(url)
  url = url.split("//").last.split(".")
  url = url.each do |word| 
    if word.include?("http") || word.include?("www") || word.length < 3
      url.delete(word)
    end
  end
  if url.length > 1
    if url.length >= 3 && url[2].length > 3
      url = [url[0], url[1], url[2]].join('.')
    else
      url = [url[0], url[1]].join(".")
    end
  else
    url = url.first
  end
end

foo 'http://www.google.in'
# => 'google'

foo 'https://www9.calendar.google.co.uk' 
# => 'calendar.google'

foo 'https://mail.google.com.au'
# => 'mail.google'

foo 'https://www12.stage.calendar.google.co.uk'
# => 'stage.calendar.google'

foo 'www.blog.botreetechnologies.com'
# => 'blog.botreetechnologies'
```